MockK - Stubbed method persists even after class mock was cleared
I am trying to stub a class method twice to test both happy and error path, but for some reason MockK is unable to clear stubbed methods per test.
For convenience I know I can use returnsMany or andThen with MockK to specify a second return value, but that will not work in my specific case. Here is the code.
This is the ViewModel which is being tested:
@HiltViewModel
class FavoriteViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val favoriteUseCase: FavoriteUseCase,
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _favoriteScreenState = MutableStateFlow(FavoriteScreenState())
    val favoriteScreenState = _favoriteScreenState.asStateFlow()

    init {
        getFavorites()
    }

    private fun getFavorites() {
        viewModelScope.launch(
            context = Dispatchers.IO
        ) {
            try {
                _favoriteScreenState.value = favoriteScreenState.value.copy(
                    movieListState = FavoriteScreenMovieListState.Success(
                        movieList = favoriteUseCase
                            .getFavorites()
                            .cachedIn(viewModelScope)
                    )
                )
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                _favoriteScreenState.value = favoriteScreenState.value.copy(
                    movieListState = FavoriteScreenMovieListState.Error(R.string.movie_list_error)
                )
            }

        }
    }

    fun scrollingToTop(scrollToTopAction: Boolean) {
        _favoriteScreenState.value = favoriteScreenState.value.copy(
            scrollToTop = scrollToTopAction
        )
    }

    fun updateNavigationItemIndex(index: Int) {
        NavigationBarItemSelection.selectedNavigationItemIndex = index
    }

}

And this is the unit test class:
class FavoriteViewModelTest {

    @MockK
    private lateinit var favoriteUseCase: FavoriteUseCase

    @InjectMockKs
    private lateinit var favoriteViewModel: FavoriteViewModel

    private val testDispatcher = StandardTestDispatcher()

    @OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        Dispatchers.setMain(testDispatcher)
        MockKAnnotations.init(this)
    }

    @OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
    @After
    fun tearDown() {
        clearMocks(favoriteUseCase)
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
    }

    @Test
    fun `Load favorite movies in ViewModel instantiation - Happy path`() = runTest {
        coEvery { favoriteUseCase.getFavorites() } returns flowOf(PagingData.from(FakeData.fakeMovieFavoriteData)).map {
            it.map { movieFavoriteEntity ->
                movieFavoriteEntity.movie.toDomain()
            }
        }

        favoriteViewModel.favoriteScreenState.test {
            val favoriteScreenState = awaitItem()
            when (val movieListState = favoriteScreenState.movieListState) {
                is FavoriteScreenMovieListState.Error,
                FavoriteScreenMovieListState.Loading -> {
                    fail("Not expected behavior")
                }
                is FavoriteScreenMovieListState.Success -> {
                    val movieList = movieListState.movieList.first()
                    assertThat(movieList).isNotInstanceOf(FavoriteScreenMovieListState.Loading::class.java)
                    assertThat(movieList).isNotEqualTo(PagingData.empty<Movie>())
                    assertThat(favoriteScreenState).isNotEqualTo(FavoriteScreenState())
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun `Load favorite movies in ViewModel instantiation - Error path`() = runTest {
        coEvery { favoriteUseCase.getFavorites() } returns flow {
            throw Exception()
        }

        favoriteViewModel.favoriteScreenState.test {
            val favoriteScreenState = awaitItem()
            when (val movieListState = favoriteScreenState.movieListState) {
                is FavoriteScreenMovieListState.Error -> {
                    assertThat(movieListState).isInstanceOf(FavoriteScreenMovieListState.Error::class.java)
                    assertThat(movieListState.message).isNotNull()
                }
                FavoriteScreenMovieListState.Loading,
                is FavoriteScreenMovieListState.Success,
                -> {
                    fail("Not expected behavior")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun getFavoriteScreenState() = runTest {
        coEvery { favoriteUseCase.getFavorites() } returns flowOf(PagingData.from(FakeData.fakeMovieFavoriteData)).map {
            it.map { movieFavoriteEntity ->
                movieFavoriteEntity.movie.toDomain()
            }
        }

        favoriteViewModel.favoriteScreenState.test {
            val favoriteScreenState = awaitItem()
            assertThat(favoriteScreenState).isInstanceOf(FavoriteScreenState::class.java)
            assertThat(favoriteScreenState).isNotNull()
            assertThat(favoriteScreenState).isNotEqualTo(FavoriteScreenState())
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun scrollingToTop() = runTest {
        val scrollToTop = true
        favoriteViewModel.favoriteScreenState.test {
            val previousValue = awaitItem().scrollToTop
            favoriteViewModel.scrollingToTop(scrollToTop)
            val currentValue = awaitItem().scrollToTop
            assertThat(previousValue).isNotEqualTo(currentValue)
            assertThat(currentValue).isTrue()
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun updateNavigationItemIndex() {
        val newNavigationIndex = 3
        val previousValue = NavigationBarItemSelection.selectedNavigationItemIndex
        favoriteViewModel.updateNavigationItemIndex(newNavigationIndex)
        val currentValue = NavigationBarItemSelection.selectedNavigationItemIndex
        assertThat(previousValue).isNotEqualTo(currentValue)
        assertThat(currentValue).isEqualTo(newNavigationIndex)
    }
}

As you can see, I am setting the stub per each test instead of inside the setUp. Even with this configuration, one of the happy/error path tests will pass and the other will fail.
Have you found a workaround for this specific case? Or is there any solution I am missing? I have read MockK documentation and the only answer I found was using andThen or returnsMany, but that will not apply to my case.
Edit: I have solved it by splitting the test class into two different classes: one with a happy path stub and the other with error stub. Still I'm not happy with this solution.
I am sure there should be another way to solve this case. I have used MockK clearMocks() method in the tearDown function with no result.
